# Gnome-terminal font doesen't show the right Symbol

Tags: fonts, gnome-terminal, neovim-plugin

Recently I started configuration NeoVim, but my bar and tab doesn't show the right symbols.
They are two independent plugins for Neovim.

[How it looks like currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cO55B.png)

I know it has to do with the font but I don't really get the problem.
I tried all the standard fronts from gnome-terminal but they don't change the strange symbols.
I also made sure that my Character Encoding is Unicode-Utf-8.

I read somewhere that the terminal actually reads the binary code for the symbols right but I don't have the font witch supports these Symbols. But I don't understand what that means.

If the plugins might be important. I have used the most part of the configs.
[The Configs I tried to impement](https://github.com/m4xshen/dotfiles/tree/main/nvim/nvim)

So my question is what do I have to do to change thes symbols?